# Monero Balance Missing in Ledger-Connected Wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization

Hello Monero Community,

I’m facing a perplexing issue with my Monero wallet linked to a Ledger device. Two months ago, I accessed my Monero balance successfully through a wallet connected to my Ledger. After uninstalling and then reinstalling the Monero wallet, I reopened a new wallet using my Ledger and my balance was correctly displayed.

However, now, when I try to open a new wallet on Monero using my Ledger, the balance shows as zero. This is confusing as I haven’t made any transactions that could have depleted my balance.

```
•   I have tried re-synchronizing and updating both my Ledger and wallet software.
•   The issue appeared after reinstalling and creating a new wallet connected to my Ledger.
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide any advice on how to rectify this situation? Your insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!